# Socket IO unexpected response code 400 during handshake

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws:// failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: 
Unexpected response code: 400 socket.io-1.2.0.js:2
```

Any suggestions for this, irrespective of research I couldn't find any solution to this problem,
any idea what went wrong on this and how can it be fixed

Node.js

```
    app.use(function(request, response, next){
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token");
        next();
    });
```

Comment: Hello did you find the solution for this?

Comment: yes I did, and since I changed code at two places, and I can't remember what fixed the code, can you please implement these two changes and get back with your findings with an answer so it can help the community.

Comment: I commented root request `app.get("/", function(request, response) {})` as well as 3 lines above in my question related to `response.header`, and then everything worked, not sure which fixed it but please try them and let me know which one worked for you